# Not able to run mahout jar

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, mahout, mahout-recommender

I am executing a command to run mahout jar for input file to generate an output file. But I am facing several errors. I have placed the input file in hdfs. The command is:

```
mahout recommenditembased -s SIMILARITY_COOCCURRENCE -i /input.txt -o /output --booleanData true
```

I am facing error:

```
MAHOUT_LOCAL is not set; adding HADOOP_CONF_DIR to classpath.
Running on hadoop, using /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf
MAHOUT-JOB: /usr/lib/mahout/mahout-examples-0.12.0-job.jar
16/07/05 00:23:47 WARN driver.MahoutDriver: No recommenditembased.props found on classpath, will use command-line arguments only
16/07/05 00:23:48 INFO common.AbstractJob: Command line arguments: {--booleanData=[true], --endPhase=[2147483647], --input=[/input.txt], --maxPrefsInItemSimilarity=[500], --maxPrefsPerUser=[10], --maxSimilaritiesPerItem=[100], --minPrefsPerUser=[1], --numRecommendations=[10], --output=[/output], --similarityClassname=[SIMILARITY_COOCCURRENCE], --startPhase=[0], --tempDir=[temp]}
16/07/05 00:23:48 INFO common.AbstractJob: Command line arguments: {--booleanData=[true], --endPhase=[2147483647], --input=[/input.txt], --minPrefsPerUser=[1], --output=[temp/preparePreferenceMatrix], --ratingShift=[0.0], --startPhase=[0], --tempDir=[temp]}
16/07/05 00:23:48 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
16/07/05 00:23:48 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.compress.map.output is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.compress
16/07/05 00:23:48 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
16/07/05 00:23:49 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-15-19.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.15.19:8032
16/07/05 00:23:51 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hadoop/.staging/job_1467669538614_0015
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: /input.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.preparation.PreparePreferenceMatrixJob.run(PreparePreferenceMatrixJob.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob.run(RecommenderJob.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob.main(RecommenderJob.java:335)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:152)
    at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From error trace it is clear that your mahout job is not able to find input file location (/input.txt).

Check your mahout configuration  and hadoop config

If you are running it Locally you can try running with 
file:///input.txt ( file protocol is for local file system) or if you are running on hdfs you can use hdfs://input.txt ( hdfs is for hdfs file system)